# problem with url being submitted to facebook comment count

Tags: php, facebook, url, comments

hit a small problem and wondering if their is a quick easy fix im missing. im wanting to use facebooks, comment count, but for some reason the url gets changed. should have &id=9 for example at the end of the url but facebook is removing everything from the & symbol

so for example 
http://www.prog3kt-mayh3m.info/index.php?page=blog&id=9
becomes
http://www.prog3kt-mayh3m.info/index.php?page=blog

heres the code im having issues with, the particular code is being echo'd from within php tags

```
echo "<iframe src='http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?href=http://www.prog3kt-mayh3m.info/index.php?page=blog&id=" . $id . "&permalink=1' scrolling='no' frameborder='0' style='border:none; overflow:hidden; width:130px; height:16px;' allowTransparency='true'></iframe>";
```

any help appreciated

Comment: Also check your <og:url tag isn't set to the URL without the parameter, as this tag should point to the canonical URL for the content, and the linter will follow the <og:url specified and scrape that page (i.e if you leave out the &id=x part in your og:url, Facebook will too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, found the solution,

replace the ampersand with `%26`:

```
<iframe src='http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?href=http://www.prog3kt-mayh3m.info/index.php?page=blog%26id=9&permalink=1' scrolling='no' frameborder='0' style='border:none; overflow:hidden; width:130px; height:16px;' allowTransparency='true'></iframe>
```

it should work ok :)

[JsFiddle result](http://jsfiddle.net/IorgaMihai/upzLh/)

Comment: thankyou very much Mihai Iorga
new their was a simple fix but, just couldnt work it out